# Structuremap assembly binding redirect

Tags: structuremap

We are currently using 2.5.4.0 in several assemblies. I would like to 
use 2.6.1.0 in my web application, but I use some assemblies that are 
compiled against version 2.5.4.0 of structuremap. Would it be safe to 
set a binding redirect in web.config for structuremap, from 2.5.4.0 to 
2.6.1.0 or would this cause any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are some breaking changes between 2.5.4 and 2.6.1, but they are small.  I imagine it would depend on your usage of the container, so the best bet would be to test it out and to make sure.

Comment: Seems to work for now, probably didn't use any of the changed stuff... thx